# Modal dialog displays from all elements of mapped array. How to select each item by ts and react js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, sass

This code:
How to display a dialog when a button is clicked using react and typescript?
I wanna open dialog from each todos, how to make it ? I used react js and typescript. Help me to resolve this problem.

```js
interface ListProps {
  todos: INote[];
  onDelete: (title: string) => void;
}

const TodoList: React.FunctionComponent<ListProps> = ({ todos, onDelete }) => {
  const [showAlert, setShowAlert] = useState(false);
  const [todo, setTodos] = useState(null);
```

*How to select each item by ts?It doesn't work. What is reason? Thanks!*

```js
  const handleOpenDialog = (todos: any) => {
    setTodos(todos);
    setShowAlert(true);
  };

  const handleCloseDialog = () => {
    setShowAlert(false);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <section className="list list--wrapper">
        {todos.map((todos) => (
          <div className="item list__item" key={todos.title}>
            <span className="item__title">{todos.title}</span>
            <div className="item__group">
              <input
                className="item__completed"
                type="checkbox"
                checked={todos.completed}
              />
              <span className="item__decs">{todos.desc}</span>
            </div>
            <div className="item__btn">
              <button
                className="item__btnd"
                onClick={() => handleOpenDialog(todos)}
              >
                Delete
              </button>
              <button className="item__btne">Edit</button>
            </div>
            {showAlert && todo && (
              <AlertDialog
                handleCloseDialog={handleCloseDialog}
                title={todos.title}
              />
            )}
          </div>
        ))}
      </section>
    </>
  );
};

export default TodoList;
```

Answer (score 0):

just add a condition to only show the AlertDialog on selected todos

```
   <section className="list list--wrapper">
    {todos.map((todos) => (
      <div className="item list__item" key={todos.title}>
        <span className="item__title">{todos.title}</span>
        <div className="item__group">
          <input
            className="item__completed"
            type="checkbox"
            checked={todos.completed}
          />
          <span className="item__decs">{todos.desc}</span>
        </div>
        <div className="item__btn">
          <button
            className="item__btnd"
            onClick={() => handleOpenDialog(todos)}
          >
            Delete
          </button>
          <button className="item__btne">Edit</button>
        </div>
        {showAlert && todos.title===todo?.title && (
          <AlertDialog
            handleCloseDialog={handleCloseDialog}
            title={todos.title}
          />
        )}
      </div>
    ))}
  </section>
```

or just move the AlertDialog outside the map

```
 <section className="list list--wrapper">
    {todos.map((todos) => (
      <div className="item list__item" key={todos.title}>
        <span className="item__title">{todos.title}</span>
        <div className="item__group">
          <input
            className="item__completed"
            type="checkbox"
            checked={todos.completed}
          />
          <span className="item__decs">{todos.desc}</span>
        </div>
        <div className="item__btn">
          <button
            className="item__btnd"
            onClick={() => handleOpenDialog(todos)}
          >
            Delete
          </button>
          <button className="item__btne">Edit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    ))}
      {showAlert && todo && (
          <AlertDialog
            handleCloseDialog={handleCloseDialog}
            title={todos.title}
          />
        )}
  </section>
```